# How to update nested record structure with lists

Tags: f#

Can someone tell me how I can update a subitem in a nested record? 
I want to set `isSelected` to `true` for the Item with value = "B"

```
type MyItem = {isSelected:bool; value:string}
type MyModel = {list:MyItem list}

let a = {isSelected = false; value = "A"}
let b = {isSelected = false; value = "B"} 
let c = {isSelected = false; value = "C"}
let m = {list = [a;b;c]}

let m2 = { m with list = { m.list with ???  = { ??? }}}
```

I will not use mutable data structures.

Comment: As general advice, find ways to avoid nested records if possible. The elm community has done a good job on clamping down on this antipattern and with good reason. Try to think about your records the way a database does. Is it possible to write nested records with lenses, helper functions etc, sure, but I'm confident you won't be a happier person.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato i Use the Fabolous Framework (Elm Style Apps), where the complete App state is hold in one model record. This could have multiple record (Like a list of items). Maybe there are other solutions to solve my Problem. But i dont know them 

Comment: In this case it's a list you can just map over it. However as you move forward with records in records in records, there's almost always a flatter less nested presentation of that data. You can almost always for example get to just two layers (not counting lists, lists are pretty easy to traverse just use List.map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `List.map`:

```ml
let m2 = 
  { m with list = 
    List.map (fun item -> 
      if item.value = "B" then 
        { item with isSelected = true }
      else
        item)
      m.list
  }
```

This will create a new list where every item is the same as before, except the one we want to "update" because we replace that with a new item where `isSelected` is `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Immutability is great but when dealing with nested immutable structures it can get a bit hairy. Especially if it's deeply nested.

One way to deal with this is so called Lenses.

So I increased the nesting level of the example a bit so that the value of lenses are more visible.

```
module Lenses =
  // This lens is a pair of function, a getter that get's inner value of an object
  //  and a setter that sets the inner value of an object
  //  The cool thing is that a lens is composable meaning we can create a lens
  //  that allows us to get and set a deeply nested property succinctly
  type Lens<'O, 'I> = L of ('O -> 'I)*('I -> 'O -> 'O)

  let lens (g : 'O -> 'I) (s : 'I -> 'O -> 'O) = L (g, s)

  // Gets an inner value
  let get     (L (g, _)) o    = g o
  // Sets an inner value
  let set     (L (_, s)) i o  = s i o
  // Updates an inner value given an updater function that sees the
  //  inner value and returns a new value
  let over    (L (g, s)) u o  = s (u (g o)) o

  // Compose two lenses into one, allows for navigation into deeply nested structures
  let compose (L (og, os)) (L (ig, is)) =
    let g o   = ig (og o)
    let s i o = os (is i (og o)) o
    L (g, s)

  type Lens<'O, 'I> with
    static member (-->) (o, i) = compose o i

open Lenses

// I made the model a bit more complex to show benefit of lenses

type MySelection =
  {
    isSelected: bool
  }

  // Define a lens that updates the property, this code can potentially be generated
  //  Scala does this with macros, in F# there are other possibilities
  static member isSelectedL : Lens<MySelection, bool> = lens (fun o -> o.isSelected) (fun i o -> { o with isSelected = i })

type MyValue =
  {
    value: string
  }

  static member valueL : Lens<MyValue, string> = lens (fun o -> o.value) (fun i o -> { o with value = i })

type MyItem   = 
  {
    selection : MySelection
    value     : MyValue
  }

  static member selectionL  : Lens<MyItem, MySelection> = lens (fun o -> o.selection) (fun i o -> { o with selection  = i })
  static member valueL      : Lens<MyItem, MyValue>     = lens (fun o -> o.value    ) (fun i o -> { o with value      = i })

type MyModel  = 
  {
    list: MyItem list
  }

  static member listL : Lens<MyModel, MyItem list> = lens (fun o -> o.list) (fun i o -> { o with list = i })

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  // Define example model
  let a = {selection = {isSelected = false}; value = {value = "A"}}
  let b = {selection = {isSelected = false}; value = {value = "B"}}
  let c = {selection = {isSelected = false}; value = {value = "C"}}
  let m = {list = [a;b;c]}

  // Print it
  printfn "%A" m

  // Update the model
  let m2 = 
    let mapper (v : MyItem) = 
      // Grabs the nest value using lens composition
      let nestedValue = v |> get (MyItem.valueL --> MyValue.valueL)
      let isSelected = nestedValue = "B"
      // Set the nested isSelected using lens composition
      v |> set (MyItem.selectionL --> MySelection.isSelectedL) isSelected
    // Maps nested list property
    m |> over MyModel.listL (List.map mapper)
  printfn "%A" m2

  0
```